# Rows not being found in Lambda function reading CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a Lambda function that is reading a CSV file, and each row is added to a DynamoDB table. I am using a print statement to print every row in the CSV to logs in CloudWatch.
There is a problem here as only 51 of the 129 rows are being printed.

Also, only a small amount of the rows that are actually found are being added to the DynamoDB tables.

Lambda Function:

```
# ChronojumpDataProcessor Lambda function
#
# This function is triggered by an object being created in an Amazon S3 bucket.
# The file is downloaded and each line is inserted into DynamoDB tables.

from __future__ import print_function
import json, urllib, boto3, csv

# Connect to S3 and DynamoDB
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

# Connect to the DynamoDB tables
athleteTable = dynamodb.Table('Athlete');
countermovementTable = dynamodb.Table('CMJ');
depthTable = dynamodb.Table('DepthJump');

# This handler is executed every time the Lambda function is triggered
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Show the incoming event in the debug log
    #print("Event received by Lambda function: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the bucket and object key from the Event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    localFilename = '/tmp/session.csv'

    # Download the file from S3 to the local filesystem
    try:
        s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e

    # Read the Session CSV file. Delimiter is the ',' character
    with open(localFilename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        # Read each row in the file
        rowCount = 0
        for row in reader:
            rowCount += 1

            # Show the row in the debug log
            print(row['athlete_id'], row['athlete_name'], row['jump_id'], row['date_time'], row['jump_type'], row['jump_tc'], row['jump_height'], row['jump_RSI'])

            # Insert Athlete ID and Name into Athlete DynamoDB table
            athleteTable.put_item(
                Item={
                    'AthleteID':       row['athlete_id'],
                    'AthleteName':     row['athlete_name']})

            # Insert CMJ details into Countermovement Jump DynamoDB table
            if ((row['jump_type'] == "CMJ") | (row['jump_type'] == "Free")) :
                countermovementTable.put_item(
                    Item={
                        'AthleteID':           row['athlete_id'],
                        'AthleteName':         row['athlete_name'],
                        'DateTime':            row['date_time'],
                        'JumpType':            row['jump_type'],
                        'JumpID':               row['jump_id'],
                        'Height':              row['jump_height']})
            else :
                # Insert Depth Jump details into Depth Jump DynamoDB table
                depthTable.put_item(
                    Item={
                        'AthleteID':            row['athlete_id'],
                        'AthleteName':          row['athlete_name'],
                        'DateTime':             row['date_time'],
                        'JumpType':             row['jump_type'],
                        'JumpID':               row['jump_id'],
                        'ContactTime':          row['jump_tc'],
                        'Height':               row['jump_height'],
                        'RSI':                  row['jump_RSI']})

                # Finished!
                return "%d data inserted" % rowCount
```

I added a Timeout to the Lambda function of 2 minutes as I thought that maybe there wasn't enough time provided for the function to read each row, but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: No other error messages? Did code stop at 51th row or missing some results after finishing iterating 129 rows?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any error message, it reaches the 51st Row and then "END RequestId: a0780732-f8eb-4f35-ae66-85ca36e48ebc" is output in the logs.

I allocated more memory to the function but the same problem still occurs.

It alsoonly adds 9 items to the table every time, and it's 9 random rows.

Comment: I think setting of Lambda function is fine (if so, specific error messages will be written). Is `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')` working as you want? Does `reader` have 129 items?

Comment: Reader has 129 items yes, I retrieved the length of the list and printed it to the logs, and 129 was the output here.

Comment: Are all 129 rows in the same file? I notice that your code is using `bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']`, which will only look at the **first** record that is sent to the Lambda function. This means that it _might_ not be processing other files that are being sent to the Lambda function.

Comment: All the rows are in the one file. Matching the return function indent with the “with” indent fixed the issue, all the rows are now being printed to the CSV, so thank you! However, there are still only 9 items adding to the countermovement table, and 5 adding to the depthJump table.

Comment: Problem solved, the wrong key was being used in the DynamoDB tables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return` statement is indented under the `else`, which means that the function will exit as soon as the `if` evaluates to False.

It should be indented to match the indent use on the `with` line.